# Is there a command to destroy all resources and recreate them?

Tags: vagrant

I'm looking for a command that basically calls these one after another:

```
vagrant destroy -f
vagrant up
```

Does such a command exist?

Answer (score 0):

> Does such a command exist?

I read the commands in `man vagrant`, no, it doesn't seem to exist *

**Compose your own commands based on your workflow**

However you can compose your own commands, e.g. using aliases in UNIX-like systems, I'm sure you can do similar on your OS (feel free to edit my answer and add one for Windows e.g.)

```
alias vgrecreate='vagrant destroy -f && vagrant up'
```

I have a few of those aliases for vagrant that are tailored to my workflow, e.g.

```
alias vgs='vagrant up && vagrant ssh'
```

<sub>* and perhaps for a good reason, a good API might not want to expose duplicate functionality and rather might want to the keep the interface orthogonal</sub>